# Qt Remote File Browser

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qfiledialog

I was wondering if anyone has worked on Qt Remote File Browser. From my understanding, I have two options;

1. Use QFileDilaog with a custom proxy model when it comes to remote files. The model will be responsible for providing remote file/directory structure.
2. Use a custom dialog and have a standard file system model for local files and a custom model for remote files.

In both cases, the process of getting remote file/directory list can be accomplished using QNetworkAccess manager.

Has anyone worked on a similar concept and am I heading in the right direction ? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I have no specific experience on this, but from an object-oriented point of view, you should try to implement solution 1 in a way where the GUI does not care if the files are placed locally, remotely, or even mixed. If the default QFileDialog turns out to be insufficient, you can then still exchange that dialog by a custom one, or a widget, or whatever.