# Is there a PyQt5 widget for drop-down "file explorer" menu?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on a small project using PyQt5 (Python 3) and I want a widget where a user can select/modify a file, somewhat akin to the left-hand side of file explorer on Windows:

[image: File Explorer on Windows]

This cannot be done with `QFileDialog` as I want to display files that are not on the user's drive.

I have tried writing my own, however I am a beginner and I lack the skills to do it correctly (hence the reason why I'm trying to learn). I can provide the code if that would be useful.

**Is there such a thing built in to pyqt? Has anyone created one before, with source code available?**

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: More specifically I don't want a way to access remote files, just a widget that displays entries (along with icons, preferably) and subentries in a sort of drop-down menu, like the section of *file explorer* mentioned above. It doesn't necessarily have to be to do with files, consider it a drop-down menu if that helps.

Comment: This link might give you some direction. It talks abt using QNetworkAccessManager for getting remote files. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22299709/7636315

Comment: Thankyou @eyllanesc I didn't even know you could do that.

Comment: @Paandittya I'll check that out. Thanks.

Comment: @Jachdich Qt does not support access to remote files, so you'll have to use other libraries along with Qt. I recommend looking for a library that allows routes, modify, delete and copy external files, then you have to create a widget that maps the routes and associate each action of the widget with the logic of altering the files. It is not a simple question,

Comment: @Jachdich [cont.] so I recommend you first investigate and try to solve it for yourself and if you have specific problems then ask it here. And if you are a beginner for it then it is recommended that you look for a simpler project (for example how to create custom widgets or create your own QFileDialog) that allows you to gain experience for a larger project.

Comment: @eyllanesec that's true, however I have the remote file thing figured out, I just can't find a way to *display* the result. As mentioned, I have had a bash at it however it doesn't really work very well (I can post the source code tomorrow if it's useful). Sorry if I misunderstood your point.

Comment: @Jachdich Okay, then you already have the business logic implemented, then you can use QTreeWidget/QTreeView to show that information.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'll check those widgets out. It's most likely I won't be able to find out if they do/don't work until tomorrow though.

Comment: According to your answer I think you better read Qt / PyQt tutorials since I think you do not know anything about PyQt.

Comment: @eyllanesc you would be correct. I am a beginner at GUI programming on general, and have only really read tutorials/docs when they are necessary to what I am doing. I should probably take some time to read the docs and some more advanced tutorials. In fact, I think I'll do some of that now.

Comment: Creating a GUI has a different approach to other types of applications, the workflow is different. For example, I recommend reading about models and views in Qt, which usually has an intermediate PyQt level, since you will use it in your probable solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'll check that out too l

Comment: @eyllanesc The QTreeView widget is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. If you would post an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old but for anyone looking for an answer it's the `QTreeView` widget.